# Node.js. createWriteStream/createReadStream Как записать в файл и по завершении прочитать?

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, request, асинхронность, fstream

Вот есть такой код:

```
var fs = require('fs') 
var request = require('request');
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Он сохраняет данные (файл) полученные по ссылке в файл..:)

У меня такие вопросы:

1. Как По завершению записи данных в файл сразу считать их снова с помощью createReadStream??
2. Как отследить или подождать, что данные в файл уже 100% все записаны перед чтением??
3. Можно ли на этот request или pipe повесить promise? или как то по-другому переписать?
4. Допустим ссылок будет много таких с которых данные будут в цикле записываться в файлы - И потом как сразу их считывать вновь, если цикл асинхронный??

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Answer (score 0):

Дождаться завершения можно через обработку события [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish):

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png')
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
    .on("finish", ...);
```

Но тут есть проблема - `pipe` не закрывает выходной поток при ошибке чтения и не пробрасывает ее дальше, поэтому ошибку надо обязательно обрабатывать отдельно!

С обработкой ошибок получается как-то так:

```
var source = request('http://google.com/doodle.png');
var dest = source.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dest.on('finish', resolve);
    source.on('error', reject);
    dest.on('error', reject);
}).catch(e => new Promise((_, reject) => {
    dest.end(() => {
      fs.unlink('doodle.png', () => reject(e));
    });
}));
```

Если недокачанные файлы не удалять, то код будет, конечно же, проще - но недокачанные файлы обычно ведут к непонятным глюкам.